# Как распечатать файл на принтере из консольного приложения?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, консоль

Есть программа на C++ (Visual Studio 2013)(Console App). В ней я составляю некоторый текстовый файл и хочу отправить его в печать.

Например, в корневой директории есть файл `text.txt`.

Как программно распечатать текстовый файл на принтере?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, вы хотите на принтере файл распечатать?

Comment: Да, хочу напечатать файл txt в той же папке, что и exe моей программы.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать так

```
system("print text.txt");
```

Или мучиться с функциями GDI:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/194320-win32-api-printer-tutorial-using-gdi-functions/

Comment: Выводит в консоль Путь_К_Файлу\text.txt печатается...

Comment: А сам ничего не печатает

Answer (score 0):

На прямую печатать на принтере есть много проблем. Так как разные принтеры, USB порты и для.

но, попробуйте следующий код, может поможет. Код тестировался на USB принтере.

```
// an example of printing in C++ to the console and a printer
// Thanks etresoft!
// by Miguel Reznicek mreznicek@pretensa.com
// Prints to local and networked printers
// Just make sure you printed to the printer you want to print
// just before this one is printed. (That chooses the printer)

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Some sample data including a prompt for a string (name)
int i=1234;
char name[15];
float fval=123.456;
FILE * printer_pipe = popen("/usr/bin/lpr", "w");
cout << "Enter a name: ";
cin >> name;

// Output to the console
// First a couple blank lines to the console;
cout << endl << endl;
// Second a string to the console
cout << "a string name: " << name << endl;
// Third a decimal integer to the console
cout << "A decimal integer: " << i<< endl;
// Fourth a floating pont number to the console
cout << "A floating point number: " << fval<< endl;

// output to the printer
// %d = A decimal integer
// %f = A floating point number
// %c = A Character
// %s = A string
//
// First a couple blank lines to the printer:
fprintf(printer_pipe, "\n \n");
// Second a string (the name) to the printer:
fprintf(printer_pipe, "A string name: %s \n", name);
// Third a decimal number to the printer:
fprintf(printer_pipe, "A decimal integer: %i \n", i);
// Fourth a floating point number to the printer
fprintf(printer_pipe, "A floating point number: %f \n", fval);
// Last a couple blank lines to the printer:
fprintf(printer_pipe, "\n \n", name);
// Closing the printer
pclose(printer_pipe);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: >/usr/bin/lpr
>winapi

хммммм

Comment: Ну в тексте вопросе ведь явно написано: **Visual Studio**. Как по Вашему этот код будет работать на Windows?